# Laravel file validation issues

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have a form to upload image field optional, Laravel validation working fine but same I have another form to update where also image field optional but here Laravel validation not working fine if I don't upload the file I am getting an error.

> The file must be must be an image

Here is my rules

```
case 'PATCH':
        {
            return [
                'name' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u|min:1|max:255',
                'file' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:5000'
            ];
        }
```

Where am I doing a mistake?

Answer (score 5):

You should extend your validation rule:

```
'file' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:5000'
```

You can read about `nullable` in [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-nullable).

Comment: 'nullable' made the field non-required, thanks dear :)

Answer (score 3):

You should add `nullable` as another rule, if the file is optional, otherwise `image` validation will indeed fail. Also, you don't need to use both `image` and `mimes` validation, they are interchangeable.